# C sockets: why is my server replying with extra words from the client message?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

This my client code:

```
while(1){
    char message[1000], server_reply[2000];
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    scanf("%s",message);
    puts(message);
    if (send(sock,message,strlen(message),0)< 0){ 
        printf("ERROR writing to socket");
        return 1;
    }
     
    if (recv(sock,server_reply,2000,0)<0){
        puts("recv failed");
        break;
    }
    puts("server reply");
    puts(server_reply);
}
close(sock);
return 0;
}
```

This is my server code:

```
while(1){
    char client_message[1000];
    recv(client_socket, client_message, 2000,0);
    puts(client_message);
    write(client_socket,client_message, strlen(client_message));  
}
 
if(read_size==0){ 
    puts("client disconnected");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else if(read_size==-1){
    perror("recv failed");
}
 
return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to send a message it always comes back with words from a former message I sent

I give you an example:

Please enter the message: Elephant
Elephant
server reply
Elephant

Please enter the message: Jake
Jake
server reply
Jakehant

Please enter the message: Two
Two
server reply
Twophant

Comment: `recv()` doesn't add a null terminator. it may be binary data, not a string, so that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: It returns number of bytes that were read. You can add the null terminator after this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is making several false assumptions:

1. It assumes that `send()` and `recv()` maintain application-level message boundaries.  That is a false assumption; TCP does *not* guarantee that e.g. if you call `send()` once with N bytes, that the receiver's future call to `recv()` will yield those N bytes in a single call.  TCP only guarantees that the sent bytes will arrive at the receiver in the order they were sent; it reserves the right to pass them from `recv()` in any quantities it sees fit to do so, down to as a little as 1-byte-per-`recv()` call in the worst-case scenario.
2. It assumes that the bytes received by `recv()` will be NUL-terminated strings.  The TCP layer doesn't know anything about C-style NUL-terminated strings; it only receives (some of or all of) the bytes the sender previously sent, in FIFO order... and your `send(...,strlen(s))` calls are not including any NUL-terminator bytes in the data they sends, so the receiver will never see any NUL-terminator bytes and thus cannot know where one string ends and the next string begins.

At a minimum you should capture the return value of `recv()` to a variable so that your code can know how many bytes the `recv()` call wrote into the buffer; it can then manually place a NUL byte after the written bytes, and that will allow you to call `puts()` on the buffer without accidentally printing out other bytes that remain in the buffer from previous operations.  You'll still be susceptible to partial-message-receives though (as mention in 1. above); to deal with those you would need to implement some logic that receives bytes until it encounters a NUL-terminator byte (or some other separator byte) and only print out the string at that time.

Comment: Just adding to Jeremy's answer, you can also send the size of the message so that you  know exactly how many bytes to read and use the MSG_WAITALL flag (quoting the manual "This flag requests that the operation block until the full request is satisfied"). Important to notice that MSG_WAITALL will block until all bytes are received, so that's why you need to know the exact number of bytes to read, otherwise your code will hang.